# Intellij How override (spring) multiline configuration properties

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

In my spring application i have to provide an certificate with format

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
ZSBJb1QgSHViIENBIENlcnQgVGVzdCBPbmx5MB4XDTIyMDgwNDEzMjg1MVoXDTIy
MDkwMzEzMjg1MVowFDESMBAGA1UEAwwJamF2YS1zaW0xMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA1BHjgtcqmFP+TUdfBYmGU/CqYfEEtD6XaVI8BpJI
yx7y58aSnoPWxek8iM86PL8E8RtMKGZkB29JSLp7BIWuEAgkSZYbtN/cmTCT0r9c
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

While i can set this in application properties by adding `\n\` at all line ends
it is not working (BouncyCastle is not able to create certificate from it) if i set this as value in overridden properties:
[image]

i also tried to replace lineending by

- \n
- \\n

So how to override this property correctly.

Comment: How would you do it in the command line, outside of the IDE?

Comment: Does it need to be an entry in the properties file? I would put a key like this in an external file or keystore and point to that file in the properties.

Comment: it seems not to be supported. know i am using separate property files and add them